# Image background removal algorithms

Tags: algorithm, imagemagick, image-manipulation, alpha-transparency

I've lots of images with a white background and I need to remove it (make it transparent). I've already tried imagemagick [convert](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/masking/#difference) and for some image that worked quite well, but still cannot be used on dark background.
I'm kind a noob in this branch of programming... Someone know some good algorithms to remove the background?

Plus, would be great if it could correctly process an image like this:
http://dev.addvert.it/cache/24eeab00e5987452d09fbeec0c7678d6_w472_h472_sc.jpg

The problem with convert `diff` is it erase a lot of the image, while the `border` algo doesn't touch the central part.
I totally understand how hard is for a calculator to do something like this and I'm pretty amazed with the results of convert, but if there's the chance of a better solution, why not ask? :D

Answer (score 2):

You are not constrained to converting white pixels to transparent. You could maybe  take the colour of the top-left corner pixel and make all pixels that colour  transparent and it will work for black backgrounds too:

As suggested by @emcconville, the first of the following two options is more succinct:

```
convert towel.jpg -fill none -fuzz 2% -draw 'matte 0,0 replace' output.png
```

or, per my original,

```
convert towel.jpg -alpha on -fill none -fuzz 5% -draw 'color 0,0 replace' output.png
```

[image]

You may find this more readable...

```
convert towel.jpg -fuzz 5%                                           \
   -transparent $(convert towel.jpg -format "%[pixel:p{0,0}]" info:) \
   output.png
```

In the second line, `$(convert ...)` just gets the colour of the top-left pixel and feeds that into the middle of the outer `convert` command as the colour to make transparent - but it is only doing the same thing as the first version.

Comment: Good answer, but I'd drop `-alpha on` in favor of `-draw 'matte 0,0 replace'`

Comment: @emcconville I'm very happy to listen and learn from your suggestion but I'm not sure I understand the subtlety of what is better your suggested way? Would you mind explaining pleae?

Comment: Sure @MarkSetchell. I discarded my answer as it was identical to yours; however, I opted to use draw's matte operation. [Matte](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/draw/#matte) being exactly like `color`, but inherits alpha handling automatically -- thus no need to invoke additional `-alpha` flags.

Comment: @emcconville Thank you very much - I have incorporated your suggested  improvement.

Comment: Thank you and @emcconville for your responses. If you see the image you posted, this is not acceptable, even if is nearly the same result as mine :( I need those images to be rendered on an user selected background, that's why it cannot be erased in important parts nor having background still floating around...